# Internet explorer does not send data to server on second, fourth, 6th and so on submits

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Hi I have a situation where I have to post a string composed of html to the server. That string will contain html and css that will be converted into a pdf using ABCPDF.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <span class="print remove-on-print" data-bind="event: { click: function () { window.openPdf() } }" /></span>


    <form class="remove-on-print" id="open" action="@Url.Action("OpenPDF")" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="OpenPDF">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" name="htmlData" />
    </form>

    <script>
        window.openPdf = function () {
            //createPrintableHtml() returns a string of html 
            var printableHtml = createPrintableHtml();
            var hiddenInput = $('input[name="htmlData"]');
            hiddenInput.val(printableHtml);
            $('#open').submit();
        }
     </script>
```

This is my server code:

```
        public FileContentResult OpenPDF(string[] htmlData)
        {
            if (htmlData != null)
            {
                byte[] ret = pdfConverter.FromHTML(htmlData);
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=PrintPdf.pdf");
                return new FileContentResult(ret, "application/pdf");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

What I intended to do here is send the data in the hidden input to the server and the server will response with a pdf file, then the client will open the file in a new window

This code works very well in Chrome and Firefox but Internet Explorer on all versions has a problem.

On first click it sends the desired data to the server and the pdf gets opened on the second click it does not send the data to the server, on third click it sends it , at the fourth click it does not and so on.

If the opened window gets closed by the user the data gets sent and the pdf gets opened.

This issues reproduces only if the window does not get closed.

Can anyone tell me how can I work around this problem in Internet Explorer or provided another way of handling this?

Comment: What's in charge of your custom attributes such as data-bind? Knockout?

Comment: if you stick an alert in the start of the window.openPdf function does it popup every time?

Comment: How is the form posted? With ajax?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin he uses "$('#open').submit();" by the looks of things.

Comment: There is not enough information here to figure out whats going on with your code. I can just give you some hints, use the developer tool in IE and see if your java script is failing somewhere if not place some breakpoints and that will give you a better idea why your code is not working. I am assuming for some reasons either your createPrintableHtml() is failing to return contents or if it is returning html contents properly, $('input[name="htmlData"]') statement is failing  ( may be because of an invalid character in your html etc )

Comment: @MartinBrown there may be a custom handler for submission which is not present here in the question